# Core Dumped while creating shared library

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, g++

I just got this error when I tried to create a shared library within on my ubuntu 14.04 64 bit system:

> ```
> g++ -Wall -g -Iinclude -c /home/pure/Schreibtisch/TestDLL/src/test.cpp -o obj/Debug/src/test.o
>
> g++ -shared  obj/Debug/src/test.o  -o bin/Debug/TestDLL.so  
> collect2: error: ld terminated with signal 6 [Abgebrochen], core dumped
> /usr/bin/ld: ld: wcsrtombs.c:99: __wcsrtombs: Zusicherung »data.__outbuf[-1] == '\0'« nicht erfüllt.
> ```

I also tried to make a simple shared library from a simple class with an empty constructor and an empty destructor, same error came.

Can anyone help me how to fix that?
If more informations are needed, I can tell them.

pure@pure-QOSMIO-X500:~$ which g++

> /usr/bin/g++

pure@pure-QOSMIO-X500:~$ g++ --version

> g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
>      Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>      This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
>      warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

And this:

> LC_ALL=C g++ -shared  /home/pure/Schreibtisch/TestDLL/obj/Debug/src/test.o  -o /home/pure/Schreibtisch/TestDLL/libTestDLL.so

returns now:

> /usr/bin/ld: /home/pure/Schreibtisch/TestDLL/obj/Debug/src/test.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_ZTV4test' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>      /home/pure/Schreibtisch/TestDLL/obj/Debug/src/test.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Analyze the core file with `gdb`.

Comment: Try building the same source code on an English system.

Comment: Yes, please do something like export LC_ALL=C (or similar for your shell) before starting the compile process.

Comment: Could you tell us whether you are using a stock compiler and binutils or whether you have installed custom versions? Please execute `which g++` and `g++ --version` and tell us the output.

Comment: @FlorianKeßeler Setting the locale to C beforehand is really needed to successfully compile a shared library with g++? Is this a joke or just a bug in older compilers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /usr/bin/ld: /home/pure/Schreibtisch/TestDLL/obj/Debug/src/test.o:
>   relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_ZTV4test' can not be used when
>   making a shared object; **recompile with -fPIC**
>   /home/pure/Schreibtisch/TestDLL/obj/Debug/src/test.o: error adding
>   symbols: Bad value collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I don't know why you get a crash with your native locale (german) and an useful error message using default locale.  However, now the linker itself tells you what's wrong: You didn't compile your object code with `-fPIC`.

**PIC** stands for *position independent code* and is necessary for shared libraries because their location in memory is not known in advance. For example, code generated with `-fPIC` uses relative and not absolute addresses for jumps.

Comment: Got it, no errors, compiled and got the shared library now! THanks!