# GCC link error "__wcsrtombs: Zusicherung »data.__outbuf[-1] == '\0'« nicht erfüllt"

Tags: c++, linux, g++, ld

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665273/core-dumped-while-creating-shared-library) i get error message...

```
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 6 [Abgebrochen]
compilation terminated.
/usr/bin/ld: ld: wcsrtombs.c:99: __wcsrtombs: Zusicherung »data.__outbuf[-1] == '\0'« nicht erfüllt.
```

...when trying to link a shared library but setting `LC_ALL=C` doesn't solve the problem in my case!

I'm on a german **Linux Mint 17.3 (Cinnamon)**. My project gets build with **CMake 2.8.4** (native repository). Compiler is **g++ 5.3.1** (Ubuntu xenial repository).

Compile command for all sources looks like this:

```
/usr/bin/c++   -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -Dfluag_EXPORTS -g -fPIC -I/home/youka/Schreibtisch/Projekte/FLuaG/build/src -I/usr/include/luajit-2.0 -I/usr/local/include    -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wredundant-decls -Wunreachable-code -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wswitch-enum -Wno-missing-field-initializers -std=c++11 -mmmx -o CMakeFiles/fluag.dir/main/FLuaG.cpp.o -c /home/youka/Schreibtisch/Projekte/FLuaG/src/main/FLuaG.cpp
```

Link command which causes error:

```
/usr/bin/c++  -fPIC -g   -shared -Wl,-soname,libfluag.so -o libfluag.so CMakeFiles/fluag.dir/lualibs/utf8.cpp.o CMakeFiles/fluag.dir/lualibs/mathx.cpp.o CMakeFiles/fluag.dir/lualibs/regex.cpp.o CMakeFiles/fluag.dir/lualibs/png.cpp.o CMakeFiles/fluag.dir/lualibs/geometry.cpp.o CMakeFiles/fluag.dir/lualibs/tablex.cpp.o CMakeFiles/fluag.dir/lualibs/filesystem.cpp.o CMakeFiles/fluag.dir/lualibs/tgl.cpp.o CMakeFiles/fluag.dir/lualibs/font.cpp.o CMakeFiles/fluag.dir/interfaces/vapoursynth.cpp.o CMakeFiles/fluag.dir/interfaces/public.cpp.o CMakeFiles/fluag.dir/main/FLuaG_image.cpp.o CMakeFiles/fluag.dir/main/FLuaG.cpp.o -Wl,-Bstatic -lluajit-5.1 -Wl,-Bdynamic -lGLEW /usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a -lGL -lpng -lz
```

Compiling this project with MinGW64 on Windows Vista works. Release or Debug build, with or without SIMD, etc. makes no difference.

The error message tells me that in file `wcsrtombs.c` (linked libgcc), line 99, memory comparison `data.__outbuf[-1] == '\0'` isn't ensured... which pretty confuses me.

Answer (score 2):

After setting the system language to english, the error message suddenly made sense:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libluajit-5.1.a(ljamalg.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libluajit-5.1.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
```

The problem was `-Wl,-Bstatic -lluajit-5.1`. I linked to the `.a` file which was expected to be a static library by CMake. Changing to `.so` solved the problem.